# How to access hive data to html page

Tags: php, html, hadoop, hive, hbase

I have some crawled data in hadoop. I have exported data from hbase table to hive table.. So now I have to access its tables via html, php etc. so that I can display it on web. Is their any tutorial or tool available for it. Please guide me thoroughly. My final aim is to search some record from web from hive table.

Comment: refer these sites..https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient#HiveClient-PHP

Comment: http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/818178/hive-report-not-working-php-application

Comment: Thanks, I have to verify

Comment: If you want a pre-build web interface, you can use `Hue (Beeswax)` to view and query hive tables.

Comment: You could develope a web project using the hive jdbc driver which give full access to hive dbs , querying support even metadata informations

Answer (score 0):

you can connect Hive with PHP to show the data in webpage.For that you need to use ThrifSQL.phar.

refer the below code

```
<html>
   <body>

<?php
// Load this lib
require_once __DIR__ . '/ThriftSQL.phar';

// Try out a Hive query
$hive = new \ThriftSQL\Hive( 'localhost', 10000, 'user', 'pass' );
$hql = "SELECT * from default.phpexample";
$client = $hive 
    ->connect()
    ->setSasl(false)
    ->queryAndFetchAll($hql);  

print_r($client);
echo "<table>
    <tr>
       <th>site_name</th>
      <th>price</th>
  </tr>";
foreach ($client as $row) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $field) {
       echo "<td>$field</td>";
   }
   echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
$hive->disconnect();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Refer https://github.com/Automattic/php-thrift-sql/blob/master/example.php